# Cognito wont switch unauthenticated user to authenticated user

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm using a Cognito userpool and Cognito federated identities to pass an IAM role to authenticated and unauthenticated users. When I try to switch a user from unauthenticated to authenticated, the developer console doesn't register that the change has happened; it is showing that I have 100% unauthenticated users.

Right now I instantiate my AWS client as an unauthenticated user and then call a function to update the credentials when they are available so I can switch them to authenticated. E.g.:

```
AWS.config.region = 'us-west-2';
AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
  IdentityPoolId: identityPoolId,
  region: 'us-west-2',
  Logins: {}
});

const updateCredentials = () => {
  const auth = store.getState().auth; //this gets the authentication credentials from a global store.
  AWS.config.credentials.Logins = {
    'cognito-idp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/us-west-2_XXXXXXXXX': auth.idToken
  };
  AWS.config.credentials.expired = true;
};
```

As best as I can tell, this is the correct way to do this. See the documentation [at the bottom of this page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/loading-browser-credentials-cognito.html), and [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentity.html#getId-property), and [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityCredentials.html).

However, my console shows that I have no authenticated users, so `updateCredentials` is not switching users to authenticated. What can be done to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

at the end call `AWS.config.credentials.get(()....)`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16899974)

Comment: it is a solution, the question was about not having the cognito user created... and using `.get`... creates it and shows up in the console

Comment: UXDart is correct, what Logister did was populate some static maps. For some reason the AWS Javascript SDK necessitates a call to get or refresh to actually retrieve the credentials. Otherwise, the user will show up as unauthenticated.